# Conversion fails when trying to Convert string to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, int

I have some sales numbers in a string column that I need to convert to some format so that i can calculate them with each other but I get this error while trying to convert them.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '-6.353,35' to data type int.

I'm not allowed to lose any money by rounding it up. It doesnt mather but in what type i convert as long as im not rounding them up. What's your thoughts?

For example i have -6.353,35 and 300,30 and i want to sum them too -6.053,05

Comment: Add sample data, add your code. And -6.353,35 - is not integer, it is decimal.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
select convert(int,convert(float,replace('-6.353,35',',','')))
```

as there are (,) Commas it cannot be converted to float,so remove the (,)commas after converting to float we can convert to int

If you want decimal values, then you should use `float`

```
select convert(float,replace('-6.353,35',',',''))
```

**Edit**
Like @marc_s suggested, it is preferred to use decimal rather than float

```
select convert(decimal,replace('-6.353,35',',',''))
```

Comment: @marc_s can you please explain

Comment: `float` is very prone to **rounding errors**, which is usually a really bad thing when dealing with **money amounts** - `decimal` is safe that way, no rounding errors

Comment: Also: you should always provide values for precision and scale of your `decimal` - if you use just `decimal`, you get `decimal(18,0)` - 18 digits before the comma, **none** after the comma - usually **not** what you want. Use appropriate values, e.g.  `decimal(18,4)` (18 digits total, 4 of which after the decimal point)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you want to convert this to a `decimal` value, not an `int`, as you will lose anything after decimal point otherwise.

The problem here is the separators that are being used when storing your values.

With your numbers, you have points `.` to represent thousand separators and commas `,` to represent decimal points.

To enable you to convert the value to a valid decimal you need to have it in a format that SQL Server can process.

A simple way to do this would be to remove/replace the problem characters before trying to convert the value:

```
DECLARE @val AS VARCHAR(10) = '-6.353,35'

-- step 1: remove thousand separator
SET @val = REPLACE(@val, '.', '')
SELECT @val AS RemoveThousandSeparator

-- step 2: replace decimal separator with decimal point
SET @val = REPLACE(@val, ',', '.')    
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), @val) AS DecimalPointAdded

-- to do it in one statement:
SET @val = '-6.353,35'
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),
               REPLACE(REPLACE(@val, '.', ''), ',', '.')) AS NumericeRepresentation
```

Aside from this, you would be much better off storing numeric values in the correct format in the first place to avoid this kind of workaround.