# Convert and sum values from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, format

How is it possible to sum my values from col2 in this fiddle example?

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/73441/1)

I can't change the format of the column when i create table because as you see in example it also holds dates.

My goal is to get the value of the sum to -5.646,20

Thank you all it works now

Now too my next question :D How can i bind the second query into the first one? I want to use this for the coalesce column.

```
SELECT col1, COALESCE(col32,col31,col30,col29,col28,col27,col26,col25,col24,col23,col22,col21,col20,col19,col18,col17,col16,col15,col14,col13,col2,col11
,col10,col9,col8,col7,col6,col5,col4,col3,col2) AS Summen from dbo.t2
WHERE LEFT(col1,4) = '1050'

SELECT SUM(convert(decimal(12,2),Replace(Replace(col28, '.' , '') , ',' , '.') ) )
FROM dbo.t2
WHERE LEFT(col1,4) = '1050'
```

Comment: you want to update that column or you want to change it for only select statement ?

Comment: is this just following on to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556800/conversion-fails-when-trying-to-convert-string-to-int, which you've just left. perhaps this should be an update to that question.

Comment: Only for this select statement.

Comment: I just want to change it for this select statement. Tanner, yes i know i wanted to explain better and startet therefore a new one and when i wanted to delete the old one it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Taking inspiration from the answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556800/conversion-fails-when-trying-to-convert-string-to-int):

```
SELECT SUM(convert(decimal(12,2),Replace(Replace(col2, '.' , '') , ',' , '.') ) )
FROM test
WHERE col1 NOT IN ('Datum')
```

The nested `Replace` functions are used to change how he numbers are formatted. SQL uses ',' as a thousands separator, and '.' as the decimal point separator, so we change the formatting to make the data appear as a number to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Yucky.  You can convert the values:

```
select sum(case when isnumeric(replace(replace(col2, '.', ''), ',', '.'))) = 0
                then cast(replace(replace(col2, '.', ''), ',', '.')) as decimal(20, 8))
           end)
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012+, use `try_convert()` instead:

```
select try_convert(decimal(20, 8), replace(replace(col2, '.', ''), ',', '.')) )
```

I would recommend keeping the value as a number.  If you want to have thousands separators, then you can convert it to the `money` data type.  However, the exact format (whether comma or period is used as the decimal separator, for example) depends on your internationalization settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can `CONVERT` to `MONEY` data type:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(col2 AS MONEY)) FROM test
WHERE col1 NOT IN ('Datum')
```